# Where the (e) parameter in the event listener function comes from

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript event handling, particularly when using event listeners like **`addEventListener`**, it's common to see a parameter named **`e`**, representing an event object. What exactly is this **`e`** parameter, and where does it come from?

When setting up event listeners in JavaScript, such as:

javascriptCopy code

```
element.addEventListener('click', function(e) { // Event handling code here });
```

Comment: `e, representing an event object. What exactly is this e` As you said, it's an event object. The name "e" is just what the author of this code chose to name the variable. You can give it a different name if you like, such as "event" or "aardvark". `where does it come from?` The browser creates the event object and passes it in to your function.